# Having a stream's streambuf persist beyond stream's destruction?

Tags: c++, iostream

Is it possible to have a stream's `streambuf` persist after the destruction of its originating stream's destruction?

```
streambuf* f() {
    ifstream my_stream;
    // ...
    return my_stream.rdbuf();
}

void g() {
    streambuf *s = f();
    // ...
    ifstream my_new_stream;
    my_new_stream.rdbuf( s );
}
```

I.e., I want the pointer to the `streambuf` object returned by `f()` to remain valid even after `my_stream` goes out of scope.  At some later time, I want to set some other stream's `streambuf` to the saved `streambuf`.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just store a reference to the `ifstream` itself?

Comment: If the ifstream goes out of scope, I still have the same problem.

Comment: The rdbuf version, which takes a pointer to streambuf, also returns the old streambuf used before, and should transfer the ownership to you... maybe that works for you.. however i dont know if `return stream.rdbuf(0);` works.. or if `return stream.rdbuf(new stringbuf("leaks"))`

Comment: If you look at (at least the g++ version of) fstream, it contains a streambuf object inside it.  When the fstream goes away, so does the streambuf.  The only way I could keep it around would be to copy-construct it into a new streambuf object, but it's not clear whether streambuf's are copy-constructable (or inexpensively so).

Comment: @Paul J. Lucas: Don't let it go out of scope then. I mean, constructing a new `ifstream` based on the old `filebuf` doesn't give you any advantage over just using the old one.

Comment: The design of the code base doesn't permit me to keep the old stream around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. `std::ifstream` constructs, owns and destroys its buffer. The only reason it's "exported" through `rdbuf` is to allow redirection of `std::cin` etc. In the GNU implementation, the buffer is a simple member (not a pointer).

`std::ifstream` does not export the `rdbuf()` member with an argument. One of its parent classes does, but this should be shadowed by the redefinition of `rdbuf` in `std::basic_ifstream` with signature

```
std::filebuf *rdbuf() const;
```

`std::filebuf` is also non-copyable.

(The `rdbuf(std::streambuf *)` member can be retrieved by casting to `std::ios`. Using this will cause the familiar nasal demons.)

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want, create and manage the filebuf/streambuf for yourself. You can create istreams or ostreams on the streambuf as you need them.

Like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

shared_ptr<streambuf> f()
{
    auto ret = make_shared<filebuf>();
    if( !ret->open("filebuf-test.cpp", ios::in) )
        exit(1);
    return ret;
}

void g(streambuf *sb)
{
    istream is(sb);

    string line;

    while(getline(is, line)) {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto p = f();
    g(p.get());
    return 0;
}
```