# Inheritance, pseudo polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, polymorphism, metaprogramming

Whilst digging through the STL sources (DinkumWare, SGI, STLport, etc..) and trying to make sense of their implementation choices (it's going well), I came across something I feel is a bit odd or rather ive never run into before.

Generally when one wishes to overload a member function in a derived class, you would prepend the base class member function signature with the virtual keyword, however at various points in the STL source this is not the case.

Here is a cut-down version of what I'm seeing in the STL implementations:

```
template <typename T> class A {
public:
    void func( ) { std::cout << "inside A func( )" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T> class B : public A<T> {
public: 
    void func( ) { std::cout << "inside B func( )" << std::endl; }
};
```

The compiler seems fine with this pseudo-polymorphism, where as I was expecting an error something along the lines of:

```
error C2535: 'void B<T>::func(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain what is going on here?

PS: This also seems to work without the classes being templates too.

'Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `virtual` keyword - when redefining a function, you are hiding the super's function.

In your case, by redifining `func()`, you tell the compiler there is a new function for `B`, which is different from `A`'s.

Though, because it is not declared `virtual`, you will see this affect only if you invoke `func()` from a variable of [type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) `B`. A variable of type `A` which holds a `B`, will invoke `A`'s func().

```
A *a = new B;
a->func()
```

will invoke the first [`A`'s] method.

To invoke `B`'s method, you need the type to be `B`:

```
B *b = new B;
b->func()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `B<T>::func` member simply [shadows](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) `A<T>::func`. When you call `p->func()` where `A<T> *p` points to a `B<T>`, `A<T>::func` is called, so there's no polymorphism.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void func() { std::cout << "Hello!\n"; }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void func() { std::cout << "Goodbye!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A *p = &b;

    p->func();
    b.func();
}
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/OXlgf))

In the C++ standard, there's at least one place where this shadowing/name hiding is exploited: `std::ifstream::rdbuf` [hides its ancestor's method by that name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357030/166749) and actually changes its return type.

Comment: Ah thanks, you learn something new everyday! Now that you mention it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There clearly is no error because these functions are just overloads: `A::func()` has a signature taking an `A` object (a reference or a pointer) as first argument while `B::func()` has a signature taking a `B` object as first argument. That is, this is just overloading of two functions with different argument but the function name.

This is done in a few places to produce a different return type from a function which is essentially trivially forwarding to another function (at least, these are the places I can think of). This is just to make life a bit easier for users although it is actually more confusing than anything else. The examples I can think of (e.g. the `rdbuf()` function in streams) should have created a different name instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is acceptable code, `B<T>::func` is just hiding `A<T>::func`.

```
A<int> a;
B<int> b;
a.func(); // inside A
b.func(); // inside B

A<int> *const pA = new B<int>();
pA->func(); // inside A
```

When calling `func` through a polymorphic type, it will call the function on the type of the pointer.